# Eager load Many to Many in EF4 using expressions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

I have two Entities: `GrmDeploymentAttempt` and `GrmDeploymentStep`.  These entities have a many to many relationship through an intermediary POCO `GrmDeploymentAttemptStep`, which has additional information about the actual many-to-many relationship.

I am trying to load an attempt with all step information through eager loading, so right now I have the following code:

```
        var attempt = _context.GrmDeploymentAttempts
                              .Where(x => x.Id == attemptId)
                              .Include(x => x.AttemptSteps)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is this eager load the intermediary table, but doesn't eager load the Steps table.    How can I use the `Include()` with expressions to eager load my `Step` entity?  Using the `Include(string)` method I could do `Include("AttemptSteps.Steps")` but I am not sure how to do this with expressions.

As a note, I know i could instead load the `AttemptSteps` entity and eager load off of there, but there are some situations where I am unable to do this and I have been wondering how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var attempt = _context.GrmDeploymentAttempts
    .Where(x => x.Id == attemptId)
    .Include(x => x.AttemptSteps.Select(a => a.Step))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`Include(...Select(...))` generally loads a navigation property of a child collection.